# null safe alternative to ArrayList.addAll

Tags: java, apache-commons

I need to safely add one collection(can be NULL) to another.

Is any alternative for example in Apache Commons in order to avoid implementation of a my own custom method like this one:

```
public static <E> void addAllIfNotNull(List<E> list, Collection<? extends E> c) {
    if (c != null) {
        list.addAll(c);
    }
}
```

I need it for the following case:

I have a method:

```
@Override
public CardPair createWithRandomCards(Board board, List<Long> exludeCardCategoryIds, List<Long> exludeCardIds) {
    if (board == null) {
        throw new EntityNotFoundException(ErrorMessage.BOARD_NOT_FOUND);
    }

    exludeCardIds = CollectionUtils.addAllIfNotNull(getCardIds(board), exludeCardIds);

...
}
```

and I'm using this method somewhere in the code:

```
cardPair = boardCardService.createWithRandomCards(currentBoard, null, null);
```

`exludeCardCategoryIds`, `exludeCardIds` - sometimes can be null and I don't want to create a dummy empty collections for them in this cases.

The goal is to avoid redundant conditions for NULL and move out them to the util method.

What is wrong with this api ?

Comment: IMO, if you find that you *need* null-safe operations, the chances are that you are using `null` incorrectly in your APIs.  It is better to stamp out unexpected `null` values at source than to be perpetually testing for them, either explicitly or under the hood.  NPE's are your friend ... actually.

Comment: I have extended my question with an example from my code. What is wrong with this api ?

Comment: *Why* can they sometimes be null? What's the point? How is that semantically and usefully different from an empty List? And if they are semantically different, why are you looking for a way to treat them as semantically the same?

Comment: @EJP The point is to use this method from different parts of my code. In a one place for example - `exludeCardIds` is a result list from Spring Data repository method invocation, in another place I have no pre-initialized lists and I don't want to create an empty ones. I think it is redundant waste of resources of my application.

Comment: @alexanoid - The waste is trivial.  Using `null` to represent an empty list is generally thought to be bad practice.  The reason it is bad practice is that it forces you to scatter null tests throughout your code.  1) The repeated null tests themselves could be wasteful (if waste is a well-founded concern).  2) The null tests are fragile: if you forget one -> NPE.